# how to enable openstack_inventory.py caching?

Tags: ansible, openstack, ansible-inventory

How to enable caching when running openstack_inventory.py?
Mine does seems to cache and takes a long time to query the inventories for ansible.

Comment: Have you followed this article already? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/cache.html

Comment: yes. it does not work for openstack inventories

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?